# compare keys in map against a function

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a `map<int, string>`. The keys refer to client nodes.

I need to traverse the map, and compare each key to every other key held within a map against a boolean function (which checks if the nodes are connected).

I.e. what is the best way to do something like

```
map<int, string> test_map;
map<int, string>::iterator iter;

for (iter = test_map.begin(); iter!=test_map.end(); iter++)
{
    int curr_node = iter->first;

    /* psuedo-code:
    1. iterate through other keys
    2. check against boolean e.g. bool fn1(curr_node, test_node) returns true if nodes are connected
    3. perform fn2 if true */

}
```

I'm not sure how to do the iteration part with the other keys in the nodes - much thanks in advance.

Comment: Just make a copy of the current iter and iterate it until it reaches the map's end.

Comment: Are connections directed or undirected?

Comment: How does the boolean function work that performs the check? If that makes a lookup in some sort of list of all edges, couldn't you simply traverse that list, rather than the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completely naive solution is this:

```
map<int, string>::iterator iter, iter2;

for ( iter = test_map.begin(); iter != test_map.end(); iter++)
{
    int curr_node = iter->first;
    for ( iter2 = test_map.begin(); iter2 != test_map.end(); iter2++)
    {
        if( iter == iter2 ) continue;
        int test_node = iter2->first;
        if( fn1(curr_node, test_node) ) fn2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a step back, perhaps you'd be better served by a slightly different data structure here?

An [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) or [matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) might work better, at least for this task you're asking about.

The gist is that you'd have an edge-centric, not a node-centric, data structure.  That would make your stated task of calling `fn2` on every pair of connected nodes very easy.

Let me know if this approach makes sense given your requirements and I'll be happy to include more details or references.